# Morning-after pill availability in Poland

Tags: health, poland, sex

I am going to visit Poland for some time, and I was wondering if there is ANY kind of morning-after pill available without medical prescription in Poland?

I am in Germany right now and they made it available here without prescription but only the person who is going to use can buy it, maybe you know if there is any chance I can manage to buy it for someone else?

The need for the pill is only in case of condom damage.

Comment: In Germany, how do they enforce that "only the person who is going to use  [it] can buy it"?  Do they make you eat the pill in front of them?  Also note that regular contraceptive pills (which may require a prescription) can be used.  There's a big guide for that here: http://ec.princeton.edu/questions/dose.html#dose

Comment: @JohnZwinck well, maybe for a female would not be a problem to buy for someone else, but I am a male and they didn't give it to me, told me that reason what I wrote. Thanks for the guide

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since last year, these kind of pills are theoretically available without prescription, however it's been recently discussed and it might get forbidden again (conservative government). What's more, we also have a stuipd law called "conscience clause" which tells that a doctor or a pharmacist may refuse to give you any kind of medicine if it's against his moral code...

Nonetheless, if we're talking about large cities and you are more than 15 years old, then you should be able to buy them in one pharmacy or another.

Comment: what do you mean with "theoretically" available? well the "conscience clause" sounds really stupid :D and according to the last sentence, I SHOULD be, but no guarantee, I guess? I mean, if it's available then it's available, if not then not, I don't understand how can there be an ambiguous answer on that specific question

Comment: @Leonardo local laws and traditions often make not much sense to foreigners. But if the situation is not clear cut, as in this answer, you as tourist will have to live with it. Better for your girl to be on regular birth control as well as use condoms, as not all mishaps are easy to spot.

Comment: @Kamil [off-topic] You can say that "conscience clause" is stupid, but probably more stupid is killing already living human, even if he's very small.

Comment: @psur I don't think this is right place to discuss such things. "Conscience clause" is not necessarily related with birth control, it's a general rule for all medical actions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscience_clause_%28medical%29)

Comment: @Leonardo yes, it is weird, but like i said - law allows you to buy such pills without prescription, but also law allows a pharmacist not to sell it to you if his "conscious" will suffer because of that :) To sum up, the more determined you are, the more chance that you will get it - it may happen that you will have to visit 2 or 3 different pharmacies before someone sells it to you. Also, because of all that, these pills are simply not available or out of stock in some pharmacies

Comment: @psur are you sure that in three days there is already a LIVING HUMAN? and this action is only to exclude that fact, not every sexual act leads to pregnancy, not even most of them... and if you go in that direction, even using condom is potential killing of human being.

Answer (score 11):

From my understanding, the morning after pill is currently available without a prescription but that may soon change, due to the conservative government. If you check out the Gynopedia page on Warsaw (http://gynopedia.org/Warsaw), you can find updated information on the availability of morning after pill, birth control pill, etc. in Poland. It's like WikiTravel for women's health. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

In Cracow you can get pill in gynecological clinic NZOZ Arka. Here is the address:

NZOZ Arka Cracow
Krolowej Jadwigi 15
Emergency phone number: +48 692464346

Comment: Are you related to/employed by this clinic?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else reading this topic: you can't buy a morning-after pill without a prescription in Poland.

As of July 2018, in order to buy a morning-after pill you need a prescription. And the doctor can refuse to write you one, just like the pharmacist can refuse to sell you pills (even if you have a prescription) - so called "conscience clause".

English source: https://www.politico.eu/article/polish-parliament-votes-to-limit-access-to-emergency-contraception/

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas sure, https://www.politico.eu/article/polish-parliament-votes-to-limit-access-to-emergency-contraception/

Comment: Good, now put that citation properly in your answer ("as of <date>, according to <article>, <claim>.") and you'll have a well sourced answer which explains why it is correct regardless of the older contradictory answers.